# Can I Pass MSDeploy Parameters to Azure Web App MSDeploy Extension?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

There is an MSDeploy extension available for Azure Web Apps; this can be used with Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Templates as well ([example](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ARMTemplates/WordpressTemplateWebDeployDependency.json)).  I'd like to pass additional command-line arguments to MSDeploy, such as -enableRule:AppOffline ([example](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ARMTemplates/WordpressTemplateWebDeployDependency.json)).

Is there documentation for the MSDeploy Web App extension for passing additional arguments, etc.?

Comment: please, consider fixing the right answer, as this one is now obsolete

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the latest schema definition for Azure Web App MSDeploy extension as below, it **does not support** the passing of MSDeploy command line switches or flags as parameters.

http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.Web.json#/resourceDefinitions/sitesextensions

You can refer to the link below for passing parameters for ARM Web App MSDeploy extension as below.

[Documentation link for MSDeploy Web App extension passing parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-arm-with-msdeploy-provision.md)

Comment: please delete this answer, as it is obsolete

Answer (score 5):

Support was recently added to the MSDeploy section of ARM Templates adding  appOffline support.

```
(...)
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
        "name": "MSDeploy",
        "type": "Extensions",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', parameters('appName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "packageUri": "https://mystorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/package/my_webdeploy_package.zip",
            "dbType": "None",
            "connectionString": "",
            "AppOffline": true,
            "SkipAppData": true,
            "setParameters": {
                "IIS Web Application Name": "[parameters('appName')]"
            }
        }
    }
],
(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Any official documentation for this?

Comment: Apparently not.. https://twitter.com/AzureSupport/status/963016106746302464

Answer (score 0):

It is actually supported, but there are some things you need to know.

- when you only update the parameters, the changes aren't pushed through. You'll need to touch the web.config. Msdeploy doesn't see this as a change.
- it doesn't support configSource in web.config, you'll need to patch each file separately.

parameters.xml

`<parameters>
  <parameter name="SmtpHost" defaultValue="" tags="" >
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="Web.config" match="/configuration/system.net/mailSettings/smtp/network/@host" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>`

arm-template

`{
  "name": "MSDeploy",
  "type": "extensions",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "packageUri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', parameters('folder'), '/', parameters('filename'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
    "dbType": "None",
    "setParameters": {
      "IIS Web Application Name": "[parameters('cmsSiteName')]",
      "SmtpHost": "[parameters('smtpHost')]"
    }
  }
}`

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3a07e809-d452-463a-b1bf-d84d48415302/azure-resource-manager-msdeploy-extension-parameters?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview